# Past perfect continuous or past progressive

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, past-simple, past-continuous

What is the difference in meaning between these 2 sentences:

> 1. He did not answer because he **had been thinking** of his holidays.
> 2. He did not answer because he **was thinking** of his holidays.

I think #1 means that he had finished thinking and then he could not answer, and I think #2 means that he was still thinking.

Am I wrong?

Comment: The past perfect version *(had been thinking)*, means that he was thinking about his holidays at some earlier point in time (*before* the time when he didn't answer). By implication, something about those earlier thoughts caused him not to answer ***later*** (a rather strange situation, so you probably don't want to say that). The simple past *(was thinking)* simply means he didn't answer because *at the time* his mind was elsewhere.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Which makes the second sentence a bit odd _semantically_, although there is nothing wrong _grammatically_ (despite what Lucian Sava implies.)  As FumbleFingers said, The problem the reader has is this: if, in that past moment, he was _finished_ thinking of his holidays, why could he not answer?

Comment: the question is quite misleading. _Past perfect continuous or past progressive_

Answer (score 2):

1. He didn't answer because he had been thinking of his holidays.
2. He didn't answer because he was thinking of his holidays.

Both the sentences are grammatically correct and show an ongoing action in the past, with a little difference in meaning.

The sentence #1 indicates the happening of the earlier action (thinking) over a period of time; it started before the time of the latter action (didn't answer) and continued up to that time.  On the other hand, the sentence #2 indicates that the action of thinking happened exactly at/around the time of the action "didn't answer"; two actions hapenning at the same time.